# Consume data returned from a WCF Service Application in HTML Lightswitch

Tags: c#, wcf, visual-studio-lightswitch, lightswitch-2012

I have a WCF Service Application hosted in IIS. This service queries clients on our network for WMI data on demand. I would like to consume this data in my Lightswitch HTML application which is also hosted in IIS on the same server. Do i need to use a WCF RIA service? I have little to no knowledge of RIA. I looked into [this tutorial](http://lightswitchhelpwebsite.com/Blog/tabid/61/EntryId/2226/Creating-a-WCF-RIA-Service-for-Visual-Studio-2013.aspx) and I'm not sure if this solution applies. The data that's being returned from my service isn't coming from a database. Any guidance on how to consume data from my WCF service in Lightswitch HTML would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LightSwitch won't directly connect to a *WCF service*, but you could wrap it in:

a) a *RIA service*

b) an *OData web api controller*

Comment: Do you know of any examples i can refer to for wrapping my WCF service in a RIA service? Is it as simple as making my queries from my RIA service? Any example or source code would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't have any examples of wrapping a WCF service sorry, but the idea is to create a *proxy* to your service that LightSwitch knows how to consume (a RIA Service or an OData Web Api Controller). In either of those you'd recreate the queries that your app needs, which then delegate to the WCF service. Does that help?

Comment: I should have updated this sooner. I was able to get it working. thank you Yann.